# Why Context.Write not working as expected- Hadoop Map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have 1 MR job and its output looks like :

```
128.187.140.171,11
129.109.6.54,27
129.188.154.200,44
129.193.116.41,5
129.217.186.112,17
```

In the mapper code of 2nd MR job, I am doing this ;

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Parse the input string into a nice map
        // System.out.println(value.toString());
        if (value.toString().contains(",")) {
            System.out.println("Inside");
            String[] arr = value.toString().split(",");
            if (arr.length > 1) {
                System.out.println(arr[1]);
                context.write(new Text(arr[1]), new Text(arr[0]));
            }
        }
```

The output of print statements are correct :

```
Inside
11
Inside
27
```

But the context.write keeps showing following output :

```
1,slip4068.sirius.com
1,hstar.gsfc.nasa.gov
1,ad11-010.compuserve.com
1,slip85-2.co.us.ibm.net
1,stimpy.actrix.gen.nz
1,j14.ktk1.jaring.my
1,ad08-009.compuserve.com
```

Why I keep getting 1 in the Keys ?
This is my driver code:

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        conf.set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator", ",");

        Job job = new Job(conf, "WL Demo");

        job.setJarByClass(WLDemo.class);

        job.setMapperClass(WLMapper1.class);

    job.setReducerClass(WLReducer1.class);
            job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    Path in = new Path(args[0]);

    Path out = new Path(args[1]);

    Path out2 = new Path(args[2]);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

    boolean succ = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    if (!succ) {
        System.out.println("Job1 failed, exiting");
        return -1;
    }
    Job job2 = new Job(conf, "top-k-pass-2");
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job2, out);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, out2);
    job2.setJarByClass(WLDemo.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(WLMapper2.class);
    // job2.setReducerClass(Reducer1.class);
    job2.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job2.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    succ = job2.waitForCompletion(true);
    if (!succ) {
        System.out.println("Job2 failed, exiting");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get correct values in output key of my 2nd MR job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `job2.setNumReduceTasks(1)` to `job2.setNumReduceTasks(0)` .Because of that it is running a identity reducer that is bringing the output key as 1, you should have 1 as a key for some records from map1 output.

Comment: That solution worked but I still do not understand why it was showing 1 as key when I was using the job2.setNumReduceTasks(1)  .. What is the reason behind it ?

Comment: You would have some records with key as 1 from map2(WLMapper2) output.Since the number of reducers is set to 1, it runs a identity reducer by which it sorts the key from map2 output in default ascending order. That should be the reason.